# AngularJS reusable factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, abstract

I feel like this is probably a dumb question but I'm having trouble visualizing how to make this work.

I have a factory used to share data between controllers, like this:

```
app.factory('DataShare', function(){
    //Share Data between controllers via the sharedItem object and the get/set functions
    var sharedItem = {};
    function set(sharedData){
        sharedItem = sharedData;
    }
    function get(){
        return sharedItem;
    }
    return{
        set: set,
        get: get
    };
});
```

It works just fine. The issue is that are several times in my application where I need to share data. Currently, I have multiple factories with different names containing the same methods shown above. Can someone advise on the best way to create an abstract factory that I could reuse to share different data between different controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new file and declare a new object.

```
var mySharedLib = mySharedLib || {}; // declare a new namespace for the shared code.

mySharedLib.DataShare = function() {
    // your factory logic
}
```

Then, the angular side:

```
app.factory('DataShare', mySharedLib.DataShare);
```

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. Works perfectly for my multiple instances.